# Excel Macro Iteration in a Range

Tags: excel, vba

Here my code:

```
Sub Makro2()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select    
    For i = 1 To 230
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
        If IsEmpty(Cells(2 + i, 2)) = False Then
            Range("C3,M3:X3").Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").Select
            Cells(2 + i, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
        End If

    Next i

    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    End Sub
```

The range : `Range("C3,M3:X3").Select` is static. How can I dynamically code it so I can use the iteration ? I tried something like this `Range("Cells(2 + i, 3), Cells(2 + i, 13), Cells(2 + i, 14)")` but it doesn't work. I've seen a lot of examples with a range but nothing how I can select multiple cells.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Range("C" & i & ",M" & i & ":X" & i)`... but [don't select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

Comment: ^^^^^ `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i & ",M" & i & ":X" & i").Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2 + i, 1)`

Comment: Thanks guys. It works like a charm. @ScottCraner The " after the last i must be deleted.